# Plotting two scatterplots next to each other with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I currently have three seperate scatterplots showing with the same x and y axis (with the 3rd dimension being the color coding) but they all follow each other downards, one graph below the other. Here is the code I use for that (in this case I have 3 scatterplots:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
plt.xlim(0,2000000)
plt.ylim(0,250000)
ax.scatter(Sales_Force.Revenues[hello], Sales_Force.Amount[hello], 
alpha=0.05, color='g')
ax.set_title("Revenue vs Amount for Booked")
ax.set_xlabel("Revenue", size = 10)
ax.set_ylabel("Amount", size = 10)
plt.xticks(fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

Afterwards, I have 2 other versions of almost identical code replacing the "hello" with 2 other words, hence creating me 3 separate scatterplots. My question is, how (and preferably in as simple of a modification as possible, if possible) can I alter my code in order to keep the exact same plots but them being next to each other side by side instead of one below another?

I also tried doing this based on another answer I saw on stackoverflow. I tried this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)

plt.xlim(0,2000000)
plt.ylim(0,250000)
ax1.scatter(Sales_Force_Before_Merger.Revenues[hello], 
Sales_Force_Before_Merger.Amount[hello], alpha=0.05, color='g')
ax1.set_title("Revenue vs Amount for Booked Before Merger")
ax1.set_xlabel("Revenue", size = 10)
ax1.set_ylabel("Amount", size = 10)
ax1.plt.xticks(fontsize=10)
ax1.plt.show(ax=axes[0])

plt.xlim(0,2000000)
plt.ylim(0,250000)
ax2.scatter(Sales_Force_Before_Merger.Revenues[goodbye], 
Sales_Force_Before_Merger.Amount[goodbye], alpha=0.05, color='r')
ax2.set_title("Revenue vs Amount for Booked Before Merger")
ax2.set_xlabel("Revenue", size = 10)
ax2.set_ylabel("Amount", size = 10)
ax2.plt.xticks(fontsize=10)
ax2.plt.show(ax=axes[1])
```

After I do this I get an error message stating:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'plt'
```

and have two graphs showing with nothing in them (some minor modification might have populated one of the 2 plots) and additionally, both the non populated scatterplots also have different x and y value ticks showing even though they are supposed to be showing the same data.

Comment: I have already looked at that question and its answers, I don't know how to apply anything from there to my question.

Comment: Because obviously `ax1` has no attribute `plt` (why should it?), the solution is just as in the duplicate to use `plt` without trying to make it an attribute of something else.

Comment: Note that `plt.subplots` creates a new figure. If you want subplots, don't use `plt.subplots` several times. Also, `plt.show()` does not take any arguments and should be called once at the end, not somewhere in between the lines.

Comment: ok I got rid of the argument in plt.show() and kept only one of them. However, I really don't follow the argument in that duplicated post. I don't understand what they are doing in that for loop and how that relates to what I have

Comment: like what is the nrows=2, ncolumns=2? I don't get how rows and columns equal 2 relate to anything?

Comment: Well, while I'm not sure what is unclear about that (`nrows` are the number of subplot rows of your plot, `ncols` are the number of columns; here you want one row and three columns), *that* would actually be a question you can ask here - although make sure it hasn't also been asked before.

Comment: ok finally I think I got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: follow up question, is there a maximum number of plots I can put side by side. I get a ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 3, not 4 message when I tried to do 7, but can't find anything online that says there is a maximum

Comment: No, there is no maximum number of subplots. (just as you reach 100 or so you may start getting problems with the visualization)

Comment: so why is it giving me an error when I did more then 3? Just to clarify, I don't mean the number of rows, I am referring to the number of columns.

Comment: Nobody can know, because "I did more then 3" is not a clear problem description.

Comment: I did this 10 times and was hoping to see all 10 plots in 1 row: plt.subplot(1, 3, 10)
plt.scatter(Sales_Force_Before_Merger.Revenues[Withdrawn], Sales_Force_Before_Merger.Amount[Withdrawn],alpha=0.5, color='lightgrey')
plt.xlim(0,2000000)
plt.ylim(0,150000)
plt.title("Revenue vs Amount for Cancelled Before Merger")
plt.xlabel("Revenue", size = 15)
plt.ylabel("Amount", size = 15)

Comment: A subplot grid with 1 row and 3 columns has 3 subplots. Naturally there is no tenth subplot, if there are only 3 present.

Comment: I can't figure this out. I used this code that you suggested on multiple occasions the past few weeks and it was working fine (regarding subplots). Now when I do the identical thing on a different pandas dataframe, I get (I am not doing anything differently than I did before): AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'scatter'

Comment: This error means that you are trying to call `axarray.scatter()` where `axarray` is an array of axes instead of an axes itself.

Comment: Not sure I fully understood what that meant? What would be the reason for this?

Comment: The reason would be that you forgot to get the correct axes out of some returned object. E.g. if `axarray = [ax1,ax2]` you try to call `axarray.scatter` instead of `axarray[0].scatter`.